# factorial function in the IO monad haskell

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I am doing the factorial function in the IO monad haskell.
I followed the example mod3 in order to do the factorial function with IO monad.
I cant understand why my code is wrong.
I want to see if n>=1, and then do the factorial to n.
Lastly adding to the (n,r2) and return.
Can anyone help understand that?

```
while :: IO Bool -> IO () -> IO ()
while test body =
  do b <- test
     if b
       then do {body ; while test body}  -- same-line syntax for do
       else return ()

-- remainder when integer-dividing n by 3
mod3 :: Integer -> IO Integer
mod3 n = do r <- newIORef n
            while
              (do {v <- readIORef r; return (v >= 3)})
              (do {v <- readIORef r; writeIORef r (v-3)})
            readIORef r          

-- ghci> fact 4
-- (4,24)
fact :: Integer -> IO (Integer, Integer)
fact n = do r2 <- newIORef n
            while 
            (do {v2 <- readIORef r2; return (v2 >= 1)})
            (do {v2 <- readIORef r2; writeIORef r2 (v2*fact(v2-1))})
            readIORef (n,r2)
```

Comment: What does your code do or not do?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? Why are you using `IORef`s?

Comment: my code is to compute the factorial of a number for example, fact 4, its return a list, (4,24). 4 is the number which user is given and 24 is 4!

Answer (score 1):

In this part of your code:

```
readIORef (n,r2)
```

`(n,r2)` is not a IORef. `r2` is an IORef, so you this is legal:

```
readIORef r2
```

So how about trying this:

1. read the IORef r2 getting a value
2. return the pair (n, ...) where ... is the value you got in step 1

Answer (score 1):

First, indent the arguments of `while`, otherwise they are new statements.

```
fact :: Integer -> IO (Integer, Integer)
fact n = do r2 <- newIORef n
            while 
              (do {v2 <- readIORef r2; return (v2 >= 1)})
              (do {v2 <- readIORef r2; writeIORef r2 (v2*fact(v2-1))})
            readIORef (n,r2)
```

Second, the while look roughly corresponds to the imperative code:

```py
while r2 >= 1 :
  r2 = r2 * fact(r2-1)
```

This makes no sense: why the recursive call? Surely you know how to write the factorial in imperative style in a conventional imperative language; start from that and convert it to Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems that are preventing compilation. The first is that `fact (v2-1)` has type `IO (Integer, Integer)`, yet you are trying to multiply it by `v2 :: Integer`. You need to sequence `fact (v2-1)` like you sequence `readIORef r2`, the multiply by the second component of the pair.

Second, you are misusing `readIORef`. You can see it's signature [here](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=readIORef). It takes an `IORef a`, not a pair.